# doInBackground() stops and doesn't finish

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I write a swing GUI application and I use a button. If I click on a button, my application needs to do some online request. I want to set a "Please wait" `JPanel` at this time. So I use the `SwingWorker`. It is all working. The `doInBackground()` method starts but it didn't finish.

I debugged the application and I see that if I create a new object, the application goes into a class `FutureTask.java` and call the method `run()`, after this it goes into `ThreadPoolExecutor.java` into the `runWorker` method and the thread stops there.

```
private void buttonBuchenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
mainProg.showInfoWithoutButton(80000, "Please wait", mainProg.getPanel_first());
           startPayment();
                }
```

After a click on the button i change the Panel with the showInfoWithoutButton Methode. After the Panel is changed the startPayment() method starts.

```
 public void startPayment() {
    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat formatDb = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date1;
    try {
        date1 = formatDb.parse(mainProg.getFreeRoom().getAbreiseBeds());
        cal.setTime(date1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EnterConfirmation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String date = formatDb.format(cal.getTime());


    try {
        boolean paymentSuccess;
        if(mainProg.getConfig().getString("terminal").equals("true")){
        mainProg.getOpp().connectOpp();
        paymentSuccess = mainProg.getOpp().startPayment(mainProg.getFreeRoom().getPriceGesamt(), mainProg);}


        else  paymentSuccess = true;

        DBController db = new DBController();
        db.initDBConnection();

        //numberOfAvailbility is the unit. 
        String numberOfAvailbility = db.getQtyOfAvailbilityFromID(mainProg.getFreeRoom().getId());

        if(paymentSuccess == true){
//----------------------------------
// HERE IT GOES TO FutureTask.java and the methode finish: 
              JsonNewBooking a = new JsonNewBooking(mainProg.getFreeRoom().getId(), 1, mainProg.getFreeRoom().getAnreiseBeds(), date, mainProg.getFreeRoom().getGuestnr(), mainProg.getBooking().getName(), mainProg.getBooking().getEmail(), mainProg.getBooking().getStreet(), mainProg.getBooking().getPlace(), mainProg.getBooking().getLand(), String.valueOf(mainProg.getFreeRoom().getPriceGesamt())); 
//----------------------------------
              String bookid = a.setBookingToBeds();

              if(mainProg.getConfig().getString("terminal").equals("1"))
              mainProg.getOpp().printReceipt(paymentSuccess);

                  if (!bookid.equals("null")) {
                  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try {
            Date checkInDay = simpleDateFormat.parse(mainProg.getFreeRoom().getAnreiseBeds());
            Date todayDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));

            if (checkInDay.compareTo(todayDate) == 0) {
                System.out.println(bookid);
                //ReturnKeyWithoutTerminal because was 100% paid already
                gui.return.returnWithoutTerminal(mainProg, bookid);

                mainProg.getFreeRoom().reset();
                mainProg.getBooking().reset();
                mainProg.getPanel_bookNow().resetAll();
                mainProg.resetPanel();
                mainProg.getBackToMainPanelTimer().stop();

            } else {

                mainProg.getFreeRoom().reset();
                mainProg.getFreeRoom().reset();
                mainProg.getPanel_bookNow().resetAll();
                mainProg.resetPanel();
                mainProg.getBackToMainPanelTimer().stop();
            }

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EnterConfirmation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
        }else
            mainProg.getOpp().printReceipt(paymentSuccess);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EnterConfirmation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

            return null;

        }}.execute();

 }
```

Normally the method should finish normally but it stops at the line where I create the object "a" (sorry for the bad name).

Maybe someone have an idea why it calls the class `FutureTask.java` and the `ThreadPoolExecutor.java` and stops the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: How do you know it didn't finish?  You've not implement a `PropertyChangeListener` to monitor the `DONE` state? You've not overridden the `done` method? Do you understand that Swing is a single threaded environment and NOT thread safe, so while using a `SwingWorker` is a good idea so as not to block the EDT, you should not be updating the UI from out side it, which you seem to be doing

Comment: And `Calendar` is effectively deprecated, you should be using the `java.time` API instead. As it stands, it's impossible for us to be able to debug the problem as there are too many outside inputs which haven't been provided. Consider providing a [mcve] instead

Comment: You should also definitly format your code. That one line is waaay too long

Comment: Thanks for your information. It is not so easy to build now a code where i can reproduce the problem because there are so much own classes. @MadProgrammer: You are right, i have add a done method and the code in the done method is started. I think the problem is a uncaught Exception. It have to be in the JsonNewBooking constructor i think. I will search it now.

Comment: @KevinJedynak In the `done` method, call `get`, this will either return the value (returned from `doInBackground`) or throw the error, which you can trap and inspect

Comment: @MadProgrammer perfect thanks! i see the exception! Thank you!